# Передача в функцию параметра с неопределенным типом C#

Tags: c#

Этот метод не будет работать, но как можно реализовать подобную логику?

```
    string s = "s";
    int n = 1;
    void do(Object obj)
    {
        string str = "";
        int i = 0;
        if (obj.GetType() == str.GetType()){
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
        else if (obj.GetType() == i.GetType()){
            obj = obj*10;
        }
    }
    do(s);
    do(n);
```

Comment: [Универсальные методы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods)

Comment: Опишите словами, что Вам надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Редко сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой. Так подойдет?

[1-й Вариант](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.12.php)

[2-й Вариант](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.5.php)

1-й Вариант:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = "Как же Хорошо, что Земля квадратная, на углу всегда встретимся.";
            int y = 124;
            var ss = GetType<string>(ref x);
            Console.WriteLine("Тип: " + ss);
            ss = GetType<int>(ref y);
            Console.WriteLine("Тип: " + ss);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
public static string GetType<T> (ref T x)
        {
            string _type = x.GetType().ToString();
            return _type;
        }
```

2-й Вариант:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Вызываем метод: GetType2 с разными параметрами");
            var gt1 = GetType2(10);
            var gt2 = GetType2("Unity 3D vs Unreal Engine");
            Console.WriteLine("GetType2(10) - Type: " + gt1);
            Console.WriteLine("GetType2(Unity 3D vs Unreal Engine) - Type: " + gt2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string GetType2(string x)
        {
            string _type = x.GetType().ToString();
            return _type;
        }

        public static string GetType2(int x)
        {
            string _type = x.GetType().ToString();
            return _type;
        }
```

Comment: Что. Это. Такое.

Comment: Я так думаю то, что искал человек :) 
Самый более менее понятный способ. 
why not?

Comment: Зачем проверка на тип? Ведь есть перегруженные методы. Просто передай параметр а нужный метод вызовется сам

Comment: лол, а где я проверяю на тип?)

Comment: @Jlovenpk1 Life  `x.GetType().ToString();` 2 метода с одинаковым телом. Можно просто возвращать в первой "string" а во второй "int"

Comment: Ба, а вдруг человек не поймет?) Дело вкуса.

Answer (score 0):

И так, кто/что запрещает вам использовать Pattern Matching?
Но для начала пример без pattern matching'a:

```
void Do(object obj)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    var code = Type.GetTypeCode(type);

    switch (code)
    {
        case TypeCode.String:
            Console.WriteLine("Это строка");
            break;

        case TypeCode.Int32:
            Console.WriteLine("Это число");
            break;
    }
}
```

А теперь открываем для себя Pattern Matching:

```
void Do(object obj)
{
    if (obj is string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Это строка");
    }
    else if (obj is int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Это число");
    }
}
```

А еще советую прочитать вам про перегрузку методов:

```
void Do(string str)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Это строка");
}

void Do(int i) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Это число");
}
```

Ну и еще 1 вариант с Switch:

```
void Do(object obj)
{
    switch (obj)
    {
        case string s:
            Console.WriteLine("Это строка");
            break;

        case int i:
            Console.WriteLine("Это число");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну вот, у тебя тоже перезагрузка методов есть в примере :)
А еще мне писал: Что.Это.Такое
Но за: Pattern Matching - Спасиб, буду знать.

Comment: Я вообще про сам код, у Вас какой-то бред, имхо, был написал, который, имхо, не соответствовал вопросу)

Comment: Обидно :(( Учту.

Answer (score 0):

```
object i = 4;
MyMethod(ref i);
Console.WriteLine(i); // 40

void MyMethod(ref object obj)
{
  if (obj is int)
    obj = (int)obj * 10;
  else Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
}
```

Comment: ссылку для чего передавать?

Comment: @LiptonDev, ну ты же умный, про упаковку знаешь, разберешься.